# How to explain that $\sin(x) = 0$ gives $x = n\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

A student asked for my help with $\sin(x) = 0$. The answer was $x=\pi n$, but he didn't understand where the $2$ has gone. This comes from the formula:

$$\sin(x) = \sin(y)$$
$$x = y + 2\pi n  \vee x = \pi - y + 2\pi n$$

A very reasonable question ofcourse, you can see here, that we used the $2\pi n$ rule, but in this special case, the line $x = 0$ is right in the middle of the sine. I tried to explain using the following diagram, but this also didn't help:

[image]

How do I explain him that $x = \pi n$ instead of $x = 2\pi n \vee x = \pi + 2\pi n$

Comment: What are you taking as your definition of sin ?

Comment: The picture you have supplied is an excellent "explanation" at this level.

Comment: `π`s do not always live in pairs…

Comment: Looks to me like those formulas say the same thing. $2\pi n - \pi = \pi(2n-1)$. So then you have all the odd multiples of pi, and all the even multiples of pi. Unless I'm missing something obvious, you are saying the same thing in different language.

Comment: Can't you use the $2\pi$-periodicity after observing that you have $2$ roots in $[0,2\pi)$ (namely, 0 and $\pi$), not only $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ as the coordinates of a point on the unit circle. The ray making angle $t$ with the positive $x$-axis meets the unit circle at $(\cos t, \sin t)$. So $\sin t$ is the $y$-coordinate of a point on the unit circle.

Then, when you are asking for solutions to $$\sin t = 0$$ you are really asking "for what angles $t$ does the ray at angle $t$ meet the unit circle on the $x$-axis?" So the answer is clearly $0,\pm\pi, \pm 2\pi, \pm 3\pi,$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one explanation:

$\sin(t)$ is defined in precalculus courses to be the $y$-coordinate of the point $(x,y)$ you land on if you start at the point $(1,0)$ in the $XY$ plane and walk counterclockwise (for $t >0$) around the unit circle -- and the total distance you walk is $t$.  Obviously, if you start at $(1,0)$ and walk along the unit circle $t$ distance for any $t$, you will land on some pair $(x,y)$ in the $XY$ plane.  The $y$ coordinate is $sin(t)$.

Check out what happens if you walk $\pi$ distance.  You land at the point $(-1,0)$ which has $y$ coordinate $0$, so $\sin(\pi) = 0$.

What if you walk around $3\pi$ from $(1,0)$?  You again land on $(-1,0)$, so $\sin(3\pi) = 0$.  By this reasoning, it's true for any odd integer $k$ (and even integers, too, except for even integers you land on $(1,0)$) that $\sin(k\pi) = 0$.